# Can't clear ASP.NET cache

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a 2.x ASP.NET application, running on Windows Server 2k8R2.

We had to make a couple of changes and when we posted them to production the new changes are not working.  When I check the physical page on the production server all of the new code is there, however the old code is still executing.

Something seems cached and I don't know where to check to un-cache it?  I quickly restarted IIS but I can't bring server down for a long period of time until later tonight.  I would like to figure out why this is happening so I can reset it now and also avoid it in the future.  Any idea?

Comment: This is just a guess but maybe you have to clear the cache on your browser to see the changes. Are the code changes you made in the code behind or are they on the page itself (i.e. script)? To prevent caching I usually use..

IE 
     `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);`  

and

Firefox

`Response.Cache.SetNoStore();`

Comment: I am setting NoCache in the page and the browser is definitely cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem but I did find a fix. When I touch the web.config it recycles everything.  So I edited by web.config, just added some black space and saved it.  Once I did this my page refreshed properly.  This allowed me to keep running the server.  If I edit web.config multiple times it will lock up and I'll have to restart IIS (learned this the hard way a while back) but for a one time update so I can keep running until I can recycle later at night, it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as refreshing the application pool. Do that instead, it's much faster!

Comment: I actually tried this and it didnt' seem to work, which really perplexed me.